# Apache mod_rewrite redirects links to localhost. How to make .htaccess to work with each site in local machine?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-url

I've installed Xampp as a web server and want to make clean URLs for one of my projects.  So I put these simple lines in **.htaccess** file in the root of this project:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Also I made links in this project like this:

```
<a href="/about/">About Us</a>
```

I expected to go to **localhost/this_project/about/**, but it does not work. I go to **localhost/about/** and this is wrong. How can I solve this problem?

I also have put this line in the 2nd line of .htaccess file, but no change happened.

```
RewriteBase /this_project/
```

Attention: There are many directories in **htdocs** folder for each project.

Comment: You want 1 .htaccess to control behaviour of all the virtual hosts you have in your Apache?

Comment: @N.B. I need 1 .htaccess file for each specific project located in a directory in htdocs folder.

Comment: Don't use .htaccess files for this. Such stuff belongs in the main config of the http server.

Comment: @arkascha I have to do it. Because I have upload all files of each project on its web hosting with its specific mod_rewrite rules. They can be different in each project.

Comment: @MohammadSaberi ah, ok that is different. I did not learn that from your question. I agree, in such case you do want to use .htaccess file. This is what they are meant for. Only this. :-)

Comment: @arkascha now do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good with .htaccess files, I try to avoid them where possible, since I find their configuration arkward and error prone. Just a suggestion: you sure there really should be a `/` before the `index.php` in the rule?

Comment: @arkascha I removed `/` from `/about/ and problem solved now. But this is not the solution. I have to solve it completely

Comment: I guess you mean you removed the _second_`/` inside `/about/`? If that helps than probably your problem is that the `/` drops you into another directory. That is the annoying thing with .htaccess file style rewriting: it is pure horror to debug. BUT: since you are testing your setup on a local server where you have administration access, why don't you enable rewrite logging? It shows you exactly what is going on inside the rewrite engine. Check the manual of mod_rewrite for the commands `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel`. Chose a level of 7, `tail -f` the log file and make a single request.

Answer (score 0):

You htaccess looks OK so I guess you are missing

```
AllowOverride All
```

In the VHOST `<directory>` block. If you server will fail after you add AllowOverride make sure you enabled mod_rewrite.